# How do i add the newly installed file manager (Nemo) in the 'activities overview' search results?

Tags: settings, filemanager, search, nemo, activities-overview

Distressed Ubuntu 21.10 user here. I recently purged Nautilus and installed Nemo as my default file manager. I previously had Nautilus added in the activities-overview search-results (under - settings>search) so that i could open e-books stored in my *Downloads* folder by directly typing into the search option in activities-overview.

My problem - Now that i have Nemo installed i can't access files in my *Downloads* folder anymore from the search option in a-o. I looked into settings>search to find out that Nemo is not present in the purview of search results shown in a-o which explains why i can't access my downloads folder now.

My question - How do i add Nemo in settings>search so i can access files in my drive directly from the search option in activities-overview like i used to earlier with Nautilus?

This is what the settings>search shows after doing away with Nautilus and installing Nemo -

[image: search>settings]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can' t.

The file manager "Files" (Nautilus) is designed as the default file manager for the Gnome Shell. As such, it also has a search provider for Gnome Shell, i.e. it can respond to a search in the activities overview, and return results. As you discovered, you see such search providers in " Settings" , "Search", where you can turn them on or off. Nemo does not include such a search provider.

Comment: Are you sure???

Comment: @Someone, this is to my best knowledge and insight. This is also how the site works. If someone else knows better, or can be more specific, another answer will come up. If that is indeed valid, it will be accepted. If it isn' t, it might be that my answer accurately reflects the current state, in which case it also should be accepted. This site unfortunately does not support giving somewhat disappointing answers. Unless someone wrote a search provider for nemo somewhere, this will be how it is.

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, I think setting Nemo as the default file manager will do the same, what are your thoughts? `xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`

Comment: @Someone that presumes that nemo can interface with a search provided.